# How to fix vowel accent issue in Python?

Tags: python, string, unicode

I am trying to print the names of files in a folder with Python, but when I want to print the name I have errors with the accents on the vowels.

```
import pikepdf
import os

dir = '/content/Documentos/'
for nombre_directorio, dirs, ficheros in os.walk(dir):
    for nombre_fichero in ficheros:
        pdf = pikepdf.open(dir + nombre_fichero)
        pdf.save('/content/output/'+ nombre_fichero)
        print('/content/output/'+ nombre_fichero)
```

output:

```
/content/output/IC-GI-PC-001 Gestiвn de Informaciвn Documentada v2.pdf
/content/output/IC-GI-IN-001 Estructura, Codificaciвn y Denominaciвn de Informaciвn Documentada v3.pdf
/content/output/IC-GI-PC-002 Auditorбas del Sistema de Gestiвn Integrado V1.pdf
```

I want

```
/content/output/IC-GI-PC-001 Gestión de Información Documentada v2.pdf
/content/output/IC-GI-IN-001 Estructura, Codificación y Denominación de Información Documentada v3.pdf
/content/output/IC-GI-PC-002 Auditorías del Sistema de Gestión Integrado V1.pdf
```

Comment: The "bad" output characters are Cyrillic.  Bytes `E1 E2` are `бв` in Cyrillic encodings and `ED F3` are `íó` in Western European encodings so a mis-decoding shouldn't result in those characters.  How is your terminal configured?  In Linux you should be able to `os.walk` with a `bytes` value (`b'/content/Documentos/'`) and see the raw bytes of the filenames.  Use `print(nombre_fichero)` and see what they are.

Comment: What are the values of `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` and `sys.stdout.encoding`?

Comment: I tried a brute force search through Python's set of defined encodings, and it looks like there are several cpXXX pairs that would produce this result. For example, `'íó'.encode('cp437').decode('cp866')` yields `бв`.

Comment: sys.getfilesystemencoding() -> 'utf-8'  sys.stdout.encoding -> 'UTF-8'.  I'm using Google Colab

Comment: b'IC-GI-PC-001 Gesti\xd0\xb2n de Informaci\xd0\xb2n Documentada v2.pdf'                          
b'IC-GI-IN-001 Estructura, Codificaci\xd0\xb2n y Denominaci\xd0\xb2n de Informaci\xd0\xb2n Documentada v3.pdf'                             
b'IC-GI-PC-002 Auditor\xd0\xb1as del Sistema de Gesti\xd0\xb2n Integrado V1.pdf'

Comment: @TurePålsson That's a pretty odd pairing (OEM US DOS cp437 vs. OEM Russian DOS cp866) for someone who appears to be using Spanish on a Linux system usually configured for UTF-8, but good find 

Comment: @CarlosBerrocal Those `\xd0\xb1` and `\xd0\xb2` codes *are* UTF-8 for Cyrillic `б` and `в`.  It seems that's actually what the filenames are.  Do they display differently in the OS shell?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to read all files in folder. It wont change encoding.

```
import glob
lis =glob.glob(r"/content/Documentos/*")

for x in lis:
    print(x)
```

Gives #

```
IC-GI-IN-001 Estructura, Codificación y Denominación de Información Documentada v3.pdf

C-GI-PC-001 Gestión de Información Documentada v2.pdf
```

Comment: It still prints the same. I am using Google Colab